# Firebird - Calculate time difference between two rows

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

**Overview:** I have tables `SHIFT_LOG`, `SHIFT_LOG_DET` & `SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY` having Parent-Child-GrandChild relationships (one-to-many). So,

- LOG table contains shift details.
- LOG_DET contains operators in a particular shift &
- LOG_ENTRY table logs different entry types and timestamp for a user in a shift like (ADDED, STARTED, ON-BREAK, JOINED, ENDED).

**Problem:** For a given shift I can get all operators, and their entries using below query. What I can't do is to find the duration an operator spent on a particular entry type. i.e difference between two rows ENTRY_TIME.

```
SELECT 
    ent.ID as ENT_ID,
    det.ID as DET_ID,
    usr.CODE as USR_ID,
    ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
    ent.ENTRY_TYPE, 
    IIF(ent.ENTRY_TYPE = 0 , 'ADDED', 
        IIF(ent.ENTRY_TYPE = 1 , 'STARTED', 
        IIF(ent.ENTRY_TYPE = 2 , 'ON-BREAK', 
        IIF(ent.ENTRY_TYPE = 3 , 'JOINED', 
        IIF(ent.ENTRY_TYPE = 4 , 'ENDED', 'UNKNOWN ENTRY'))))) as ENTRY_TYPE_VALUE, 
    ent.ENTRY_TIME+cast('31.12.1899' as timestamp) as ENTRY_TIME
FROM SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY ent
LEFT JOIN SHIFT_LOG_DET det on det.ID = ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID
LEFT JOIN SHIFT_LOG log on log.ID = det.SHIFT_LOG_ID
LEFT JOIN USERS usr on usr.USERID = det.OPERATOR_ID
WHERE log.ID = 1

GROUP BY 
usr.CODE,
ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
det.ID,
ent.ID,
ENTRY_TYPE_VALUE,
ent.ENTRY_TIME,
ent.ENTRY_TYPE
```

**Result Set:**

[image]

So Inteval is the time spent in secs on a perticular ENTRY_TYPE. i.e

```
ROW(1).Interval = ( Row(2).EntryTime - Row(1).EntryTime )
```

Entry type `ENDED` has no interval as there is no other entry for the user after the shift has ended.

Firebird version is 2.5.3

Comment: Note that 2.5.3 is pretty old, the last 2.5.x is 2.5.9, and the current latest version 3.0.4.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know, but cant really do much about the version right now.

Comment: What is the calculation that needs to be done. Could you write out the calculation for one of the operators - using the example data - how to come to your expected result. I think this is probably a lot simpler to do with Firebird 3 using window functions like `LAG` and `LEAD`.

Comment: I've updated the result set with what calculcations I am after.

Comment: this use of nested `IIF` is crazy - use `CASE` operation or its shorthand `DECODE` function. Or perhaps make a dcitionare table with EVENT IDs and NAMEs to join with.

Comment: why do you select both `det.ID` and `ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID` if they should always be equal to one another (or NULL) ?

Comment: They just get selected while I was building the query, Shouldn't have included both. This isn't even an issue.

Comment: @AlphaTry it is not an issue for your program, perhaps. But it makes harder for us to speculate what specific set of columns define the "batch", what set of columns should be equal within rows #1 till #7 and differ between #7 and #8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to select the next date from the relevant entries. You can do this using something like:

```
select
  SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
  ENTRY_TIME,
  datediff(minute from ENTRY_TIME to NEXT_ENTRY_TIME) as DURATION
from (
  select 
    a.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
    a.ENTRY_TIME, 
    (select min(ENTRY_TIME) 
     from SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY 
     where SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID = a.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID
     and ENTRY_TIME > a.ENTRY_TIME) as NEXT_ENTRY_TIME
  from SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY a
) b
```

See also this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=ece84ac17427cc52a1d6ffccc663e17e).

In Firebird 3, you can use the [window function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs) `LEAD` to achieve this:

```sql
select
  SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
  ENTRY_TIME,
  datediff(minute from ENTRY_TIME 
      to lead(ENTRY_TIME) over (partition by SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID order by ENTRY_TIME)) as DURATION
from SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY
```

## Full solution

This solution was contributed by [AlphaTry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5702164/alphatry)

```
select
    ENT_ID,
    DET_ID,
    USR_CODE,
    SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
    ENTRY_TYPE, 
    ENTRY_TYPE_VALUE,
    ENTRY_TIME,
    datediff(second from ENTRY_TIME to NEXT_ENTRY_TIME) as DURATION
from (
    SELECT 
        ent.ID as ENT_ID,
        det.ID as DET_ID,
        usr.CODE as USR_CODE,
        ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
        ent.ENTRY_TYPE as ENTRY_TYPE, 
        case (ent.ENTRY_TYPE)
        when '0' then 'ADDED'
        when '1' then 'STARTED'
        when '2' then 'ON-BREAK'
        when '3' then 'JOINED'
        when '4' then 'ENDED'
        else 'UNKNOWN ENTRY'
        end as ENTRY_TYPE_VALUE,
        ent.ENTRY_TIME+cast('31.12.1899' as timestamp) as ENTRY_TIME, 
        (
            select min(ENTRY_TIME) 
            from SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY 
            where SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID = ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID
            and ENTRY_TIME > ent.ENTRY_TIME
            
        )+cast('31.12.1899' as timestamp) as NEXT_ENTRY_TIME
    FROM SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY ent
    LEFT JOIN SHIFT_LOG_DET det on det.ID = ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID
    LEFT JOIN SHIFT_LOG log on log.ID = det.SHIFT_LOG_ID
    LEFT JOIN USERS usr on usr.USERID = det.OPERATOR_ID
    WHERE log.ID = 1
    GROUP BY 
    usr.CODE,
    ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
    det.ID,
    ent.ID,
    ENTRY_TYPE_VALUE,
    ent.ENTRY_TIME,
    ent.ENTRY_TYPE
) b
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different, "pro-active" approach. Whether it can fit your workflow decide for yourself. It is based upon adding special extra column just to link adjacent rows together.

Since `LOG_ENTRY` is a log of events, and events from same source, and events rather long (15 seconds is a lot for computer), I would assume that

1. Data is only added to the table, it is very rarely or never is edited or deleted
2. Data is added in ordered manner, that is when any event is being inserted - it is the LAST event in the batch (in your case batch seems to mean: for the given operator and the given shift).

If those assumptions hold, I'd add one more (indexed!) column to the table: `batch_internal_id`. It will start as zero on your selected row #1, will be 1 on the next row, will be 2 on the row #3 and so forth. It will be reset back to zero when the batch changes (on row #8 in your screenshot).

After that the calculation of time elapsed would be a simple continuous self-join, which should usually be faster, than having many sub-selects, one per row.

Something like that:

```
SELECT 
    ent.ID as ENT_ID,
    ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID,
    ent.ENTRY_TYPE, 
    DECODE(ent.ENTRY_TYPE, 0 , 'ADDED', 1 , 'STARTED', 2 , 'ON-BREAK', 
          3 , 'JOINED', 4 , 'ENDED', 'UNKNOWN ENTRY') 
       as ENTRY_TYPE_VALUE,  -- better make it an extra table to join!
    ent.ENTRY_TIME+cast('31.12.1899' as timestamp) as ENTRY_TIME,
    ent_next.ENTRY_TIME - ent.ENTRY_TIME as time_elapsed

FROM SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY ent
LEFT JOIN SHIFT_LOG_ENTRY ent_next ON
   (ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID = ent_next.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID) and 
   (ent.batch_internal_id + 1 = ent_next.batch_internal_id)

ORDER BY ent.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID, ent.batch_internal_id
```

The trick then would be to ensure correct filling of `batch_internal_id` within every batch and at the same time isolated from other batches.

Here is where the assumptions above become important.
You can easily auto-fill the new internal (batch-relative) ID field from a SQL [trigger](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-trgr.html), providing that you made the warranty, that the event being inserted is always last in the batch.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SHIFT_LOG_DET_LINK_EVENTS
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT
  ON SHIFT_LOG_DET
AS
BEGIN
  NEW.batch_internal_id = 0;

  SELECT FIRST(1)  -- we only need one last row per same batch
    prev.batch_internal_id + 1  -- next value
  FROM SHIFT_LOG_DET prev
    WHERE prev.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID = NEW.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID -- batch definition
    ORDER BY prev.ENTRY_TIME DESCENDING
    INTO NEW.batch_internal_id;
END
```

Such a trigger would initialize the relative ID with zero when new batch is started and with incremented last ID if there already were other rows for the batch.

It however is critically dependent upon always be called in-order when all the same batch's previous rows were already inserted and none of next rows was inserted yet.

One can also write the command a bit more laconic but maybe harder to read.

```
.......
AS
BEGIN
  NEW.batch_internal_id = 
    COALESCE( (
       SELECT FIRST(1)  -- we only need one last row per same batch
           prev.batch_internal_id + 1  -- next value
       FROM SHIFT_LOG_DET prev
       WHERE prev.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID = NEW.SHIFT_LOG_DET_ID -- batch definition
       ORDER BY prev.ENTRY_TIME DESCENDING 
    ) , 0);
END
```